# mainThread implementaion in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am doing some stuffs in objective C (iOS) but stuck in a crash which happens sometimes only. Here is my code (which is inside a block getting called when a txn gets complete).

```
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //array which is used to show table view rows
        //someOtherArray is array which has data from response of a txn
        myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:someOtherArray] ;
        [self callSomeMethod] ;
    }) ;
```

the callSomeMethod is as below

```
- (void) callSomeMethod`{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //reload tableview here
    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic] ;
}) ;
}
```

my questions:
1. is this okay to call mainThread inside a main thread, as here I am calling a method **callSomeMethod** and I hv another main thread inside that method ?

2. By the time my table view is busy in reloading the section 0, the response came again and the content of myArray got changed so the application is crashing.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks a ton.

EDIT: 
My exact requirements are. 
1. Have multiple sections 
2. Can move the sections up n down 
3. Have multiple txns which are updating frequently and I hv to update tableview accordingly
4. Reloading the tableview sections when I am getting the response from server and that s changing the contents of data source array

Comment: Can you post crashing log, what is the error message? Also is there a reason you need to have another dispatch_async in callSomeMethod? try to remove the dispatch_async. One possible problem is you change the datasource of tableView, before updating the content, tableView try to reference old data which will cause the problem.

Comment: Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1914.84/UITableView.m:1037 This is the similar log I get when it crashes. (Damm it s not crashing now) also I noticed one thing the number in last part of this log (UITableView.m:1037) is different for my log. You are correct about the last line you have mentioned. I hv updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

It can be dangerous to call a table update asynchronously after you've updated the data that you're performing the data update for.

In your example, you are essentially doing the following:
1) `myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:someOtherArray];`
2) dispatch asynchronously to main
3) `[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];`

Say shortly after, you tried doing something like the following:
4) `[myArray insertObject:newObject atIndex:0];`
5) dispatch asynchronously to main
6) `[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];`

In the above examples, you need 3) to happen after 1), but not after 4). If 3) happens after 4), 3)'s refresh will cause the refresh you desired, as well as the row insert. By the time 6) is then hit, it will be trying to insert a row that has already been inserted, and the app will crash.

Because of your asynchronous dispatch's on 2) and 5), the above scenario can happen, where 3) can get called after 4).

To fix this, get rid of the asynchronous dispatches between your data updates and table refreshes. In the above example, that would involve getting rid of 2), and any other similar instances of it, such as 5).

Comment: Hello Ben, thanks for your response. I tried it and its working. But as my application is getting crashes sometimes only (say one crash in 40 attempts). Thanks :)

Comment: No problem! Let me know if there's anything I can do to help you with your remaining issue. Also, if you think my answer has solved the question you currently asked, don't forget to mark my answer as correct!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is ok to call dispatch_async to the main queue again. However, keep in mind what dispatch_async does. Since it's performing asynchronously, `callSomeMethod` will not occur in the same execution flow as the first dispatch_async call. As for your crashing, does `callSomeMethod` need to dispatch_async to the main queue? It might help to remove the dispatch_async in `callSomeMethod` and just ensure that whoever is calling `callSomeMethod` does it on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. is there any other way to make sure that callSomeMethod is running on main thread. I tried by checking [NSThread currentThread] but found dispatch_async more suitable.

Comment: NSThread has a class method called `isMainThread` that returns a BOOL

Answer (score 0):

Using `dispatch_sync` to synchronously launch to the main thread from the main thread will halt your app. Using `dispatch_async` is safe from any thread.

If you are having trouble with table data updating while the table is loading cells, you'll have to stop that from happening. Store your data somewhere else and only call `reloadData` once you've fully updated.

Comment: Thanks Ian, I am using dispatch_async only but it looks like the content of myArray are getting changed in middle of  calling  reloadData method and before the execution of tableview data source methods for all visible rows. I may be wrong here.

Comment: Don't call `reloadData` until you have finished receiving data.

Comment: thanks, but in my application the response can come any time. There are multiple background threads which are updating the same array for different purpose. and I need to udpdate the UITableView according to response.

Comment: Then use a second array and only swap it in once your update is complete. If you have to, set the table view's delegate and datasource to `nil`.